# Contar registros de visitas en diferentes períodos

Tags: php, mysql

¡Saludos!

Poseo una tabla de registros de `usuario`, una `producto` y otra de `visita`. En la tabla visita almacena el identificador del usuario, el identificador de producto y una marca de tiempo (DATETIME), etc...

Intento realizar una consulta con 5 parámetros para obtener las visitas de cada productos en intervalos de: hoy, esta semana, este mes, este año, todas (los parámetros).

Solo logro preparar la consulta hasta 1 parámetro (cualquiera de los 5):

```
SELECT producto.*, COUNT(visita.id) AS SEMANA FROM productos
LEFT JOIN visita ON visita.producto = producto.id
WHERE visita.fecha >= $parametro_php
```

Comment: Hola, Yenny. ¿Tú quieres que en la misma consulta te retorne los 5 intervalos?

Comment: Exactamente, que vengan como columnas en la consulta

Comment: Uhm, así a primeras, se me ocurre que tendrás que hacer 1 subquery en el `SELECT` por cada intervalo Oo (enlazadas todas por el id de producto).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si siempre vas a tener los mismos 5 parámetros, tal vez no sea necesario enviarles un parámetro, ya que la fecha la puedes obtener de sistema.

```
SELECT
 producto.*,
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM visita v2 WHERE v2.producto = visita.producto WHERE v2.fecha >= SUBDATE(NOW(), 7)) AS SEMANA ,
 -- aquí completas con el resto de las subqueries: hoy, este mes, este año, todas
FROM productos
LEFT JOIN visita ON visita.producto = producto.id
```

Si no quieres que se use la fecha de sistema, en lugar de `NOW()`, usas una fecha enviada por parámetro.